# Data not retrieved from previous page, passing from intent

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent

My app requires the data in the page to pass to another page, but apparantly, data are not passed, and I'm unsure of the error. Following is the warning code and error code.

```
W/System.err(18031): org.json.JSONException: No value for employ
W/System.err(18031):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
W/System.err(18031):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:548)
W/System.err(18031):    at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$GetEmployeeDetails.doInBackground(EmployeePayslip.java:138)
W/System.err(18031):    at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$GetEmployeeDetails.doInBackground(EmployeePayslip.java:1)
W/System.err(18031):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err(18031):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
W/System.err(18031):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err(18031):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
W/System.err(18031):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
W/System.err(18031):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/ViewRootImpl(18031): sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
```

This is the code for the java class.

```
package com.example.splashscreentwo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EmployeePayslip extends Activity {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String pid;
    TextView employeeName;
    TextView Desc;
    TextView txtCreatedAt;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray payslip = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> payslipList;

    // url to get all fulltime employees list
    private static String url_payslip = "http://rollit.sg/FYP/ExportPayslip.php";
    private static String url_employees = "http://rollit.sg/FYP/Existing_employees_FullTime.php";

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PAYSLIP = "payslip";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PAYSLIPNO = "payslipno";
    private static final String TAG_NETSALARY = "netsalary";
    private static final String TAG_ISSUEDATE = "issuedate";
    private static final String TAG_STARTOFPAYSLIP = "startofpayslip";
    private static final String TAG_ENDOFPAYSLIP = "endofpayslip";
    private static final String TAG_TYPEOFALLOWANCE = "typeofallowance";
    private static final String TAG_ALLOWANCEAMT = "allowanceamt";
    private static final String TAG_ALLOWANCEDATE = "allowancedate";
    private static final String TAG_AVAILABLEALLOWANCE = "availableallowance";
    private static final String TAG_TYPEOFDEDUCTION = "typeofdeduction";
    private static final String TAG_DEDUCTIONAMT = "deductionamt";
    private static final String TAG_DEDUCTIONDATE = "deductiondate";
    private static final String TAG_AGREEDOVERTIMERATE = "agreedovertimerate";
    private static final String TAG_OVERTIMERATE = "overtimerate";
    private static final String TAG_STARTOFOVERTIMEPERIOD = "startofovertimeperiod";
    private static final String TAG_ENDOFOVERTIMEPERIOD = "endofovertimeperiod";
    private static final String TAG_BASICSALARY = "basicsalary";
    private static final String TAG_EXTRAPAYMENT = "extrapayment";

    private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "employ";
    private static final String TAG_SALARY = "pay";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";




    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.employeepayslip);




     payslipList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     // Loading all fulltime employees in Background Thread
     // getting employee details from intent
     Intent i = getIntent();

     // getting employee id (pid) from intent
     pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);


     new GetEmployeeDetails().execute();

    }
    class GetEmployeeDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EmployeePayslip.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading employees details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting employee details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread

                     // Check for success tag
                     int success;
                     try {
                         // Building Parameters
                         List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                         params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                         // getting employee details by making HTTP request
                         // Note that employee details url will use GET request
                         JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                 url_employees, "GET", params1);

                         // check your log for json response
                         Log.d("Employee Details", json.toString());

                         // json success tag
                         success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                         if (success == 1) {
                             // successfully received employee details
                             JSONArray employeeObj = json
                                     .getJSONArray(TAG_EMPLOYEE); // JSON Array

                             // get first employee object from JSON Array
                             JSONObject employee = employeeObj.getJSONObject(0);

                             // employee with this pid found
                             // Edit Text
                             employeeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.employeeName);

                             Desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.departmenttext);

                             // display employee data in EditText
                             employeeName.setText(employee.getString(TAG_NAME));

                             Desc.setText(employee.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                         }else{
                             // employee with pid not found
                         }
                     } catch (JSONException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }



}
```

This is the code for the previous page. Data from this page are to pass to the another page above.

```
 package com.example.splashscreentwo;

 import java.util.ArrayList; 
 import java.util.HashMap; 
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair; 
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException; 
 import org.json.JSONObject;


 import android.app.ListActivity; 
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent; 
 import android.os.AsyncTask; 
 import android.os.Bundle; 
 import android.telephony.SmsManager; 
 import android.util.Log; 
 import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
 import android.view.View; 
 import android.widget.AdapterView; 
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

 import android.widget.ImageButton; 
 import android.widget.ListAdapter; 
 import android.widget.ListView; 
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter; 
 import android.widget.TextView;


 public class AllFTemployeesActivity extends ListActivity 
 {
 LayoutInflater inflater;    // Progress Dialog
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 // Creating JSON Parser object
 JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> employeesList;

 // url to get all fulltime employees list

  private static String url_employees = "http://rollit.sg/FYP/Existing_employees_FullTime.php";

 // JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "employee";
 private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
 private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";


 // products JSONArray
 JSONArray employee = null;     private ListView listview;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.all_ft_employees);


     ImageButton ButtonPT = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnpt);
     ImageButton BtnAddEmployee = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addEmployeeBtn);

     BtnAddEmployee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             // Launching emplopyee regstration Activity
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterEmployeeActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);

             finish();

         }
     });

     ButtonPT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             // Launching All fulltime employees Activity
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllPTemployeesActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);

             finish();

         }
     });



     // Hashmap for ListView
    employeesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

     // Loading all fulltime employees in Background Thread
     new LoadAllEmployee().execute();

     // Get listview

     ListView lv = getListView();
     lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);


     //inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //  View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planets_heade_view, null);

    // lv.addHeaderView(header);

      // on seleting single fulltime employee
      // launching Edit single fulltime employee Screen
     lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
             // getting values from selected ListItem
             String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                     .toString();


             // Starting new intent
             Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                   EmployeePayslip.class);
             // sending pid to next activity
             in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

             // starting new activity and expecting some response back
             startActivityForResult(in, 100);
         }
     });

 }    // Response from Edit single fulltime employee Activity
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     // if result code 100
     if (resultCode == 100) {
         // if result code 100 is received
         // means user edited/deleted employee
         // reload this screen again
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent);


     }

 }

 /**
  * Background Async Task to Load all fulltime employees by making HTTP Request
  * */
 class LoadAllEmployee extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     /**
      * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
      * */
     @Override
   //  protected void onPreExecute() {
      //   super.onPreExecute();
       //  pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
       //  pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        // pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       //  pDialog.setCancelable(false);
       //  pDialog.show();    //     }  //
     /**
      * getting All fulltime employees from url
      * */
     protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
         // Building Parameters
         List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
         // getting JSON string from URL
         JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_employees, "GET", params);

         // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
         Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

         try {
             // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
             int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

             if (success == 1) {
                 // fulltime employees found
                 // Getting Array of fulltime employees
                 employee = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EMPLOYEE);

                 // looping through All fulltime employees
                 for (int i = 0; i < employee.length(); i++) {
                     JSONObject c = employee.getJSONObject(i);

                     // Storing each json item in variable
                     String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                     String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                     String description= c.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION);


                     // creating new HashMap
                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                     map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                     map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                     employeesList.add(map);
                 }
             } else {
                 // no fulltime employee found
                 // Launch Add New employee Activity
              //   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                 //        NewProductActivity.class);
                 // Closing all previous activities
              //   i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               //  startActivity(i);
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return null;
     }
     /**
      * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
      * **/
     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
         // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
       //  pDialog.dismiss();


         // updating UI from Background Thread
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 /**
                  * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                  * */

                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                         AllFTemployeesActivity.this, employeesList,
                         R.layout.list_item_ft, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                 TAG_NAME,TAG_DESCRIPTION},
                         new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name, R.id.description});

                 // updating listview
                 setListAdapter(adapter);


             }
         });

     }


 }   }
```

What is wrong with the codes? Am I missing out something? If so, please guide me along, thanks and i appreciate any help given!

SO there was a spelling error with the string. After correcting the spelling in String, i got this error instead.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2421): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
E/AndroidRuntime(2421): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6833)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1082)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:2120)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.TableLayout.requestLayout(TableLayout.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16775)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:7660)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4446)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4283)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4258)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$GetEmployeeDetails.doInBackground(EmployeePayslip.java:153)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$GetEmployeeDetails.doInBackground(EmployeePayslip.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
E/AndroidRuntime(2421):     ... 4 more
D/AbsListView(2421): onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
D/AbsListView(2421): unregisterIRListener() is called 
D/AbsListView(2421): unregisterIRListener() is called 
E/WindowManager(2421): Activity com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42e528b0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-640,230} that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(2421): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42e528b0 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-640,230} that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:454)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip$GetEmployeeDetails.onPreExecute(EmployeePayslip.java:111)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at com.example.splashscreentwo.EmployeePayslip.onCreate(EmployeePayslip.java:93)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2270)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2362)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:168)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1329)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
E/WindowManager(2421):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure this part is correct: 
private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "employ";
And put your JSON output please.

Comment: On your update.. see the _Caused by_ line... ***Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.***

Comment: So, how do I go about solving it?

Comment: Read up about it in Android documentation. Only the UI thread can modify elements on the UI. Your background threads can only send signals to the UI thread, not update the UI directly. This is a restriction by architecture.

Comment: then is it possible to send signals to the UI thread that can update the UI?

Comment: i think i get you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following in `EmployeePayslip`

```
 // Loading all fulltime employees in Background Thread
 // getting employee details from intent
 Intent i = getIntent();

 // getting employee id (pid) from intent
 pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);
```

give a try with following

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null)
{
    pid = extras.getString(TAG_PID);
}
```

**Edited:** Seems *@user666* is correct. First correct the spelling of `TAG_EMPLOYEE` in both classes as follow:

```
private static final String TAG_EMPLOYEE = "employee";
```

Comment: i did both of the following and i ended up with some errors, posted up ^

Comment: Add a break point in EmployeePayslip class GetEmployeeDetails async task's doInBackground() method at line#138 at    JSONArray employeeObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_EMPLOYEE); // JSON Array Application is not able to find the node for **employ** make sure you are adding "employ" as node and not "employee" in AllFTemployeesActivity

Comment: what do u mean a break point? Sorry i do not really understand the statement. And i changed the node names to employees already. @tabrejKhan

Comment: Goto line#138 and press Ctrl+Shift+B and run the build in debug mode (press F11) and when your reach the desired view Eclipse will pause the application at line#138 and you can view the variable's value by hovering your mouse over the variables.

Comment: okay.. i do see the variable values, such as employeeObj, json, params1, success, and params. So what do i do now?